# Python collections Counter not working

Tags: python, list, counter

I'm trying to use the `Counter()` function, which is usually simple and works without issue..

I've got the following:

```
name_freq = []

for names in list.names:

    name_freq.append(names)

print(Counter(name_freq).most_common(3))
```

and I'm running into a really strange issue. It counts every single item as `1`, even duplicates.

Example count result: `[{'bob':1, 'bill':1, 'bob':1}]`

I didn't even think that was possible in Python `list[]`. The spelling and capitalization is the exact same.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Show a minified version of `list.names`. On another note, `most_common` does not return a list of dict.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye list.names = (bob, bill, jim, john)

Comment: What were you expecting? Each item does not occur more than once.

Comment: That was just an example. There are numerous duplicates in `list.names`

Answer (score 2):

Works also for me with a simple tuple. Try if this works. If, focus your effort on the list.names object

```
from collections import Counter

name_freq = []
list_names = ('bob', 'bill', 'jim', 'john', 'bob')

for names in list_names:

    name_freq.append(names)

print(Counter(name_freq).most_common(3))
```

Comment: Yeah that's working, so it's definitely an issue with `list.names`

Comment: if they are objects, not strings, then they may not be counted as "same", in your comment you state "(bob, bill, jim, john)" without the "" or '' -> if this leads you to the solution you may want to vote up the post or even set it to the preferred solution ;-) Thanks

Comment: That's how it's showing up when I print `list.names` in the console.

Comment: without understanding more about the layout of your list.xxx it is difficult to assist. Can you post how this list is being initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly in my system.
Run it once again.

Comment: I have been running it for a while. It's not working for me. It returns `[(x, 1), (y, 1), (x, 1)]` instead of `[(x, 2), (,y, 1)...`

Comment: if names=['bill','bob','bob']                                                                                                  it returns [('bob', 2), ('bill', 1)]

Answer (score 0):

```
 nameoverall =[]
 names =[["aa","bb","cc"],["aa","cc"],["dd"],["ee"]]
 for namelist in names:
     nameoverall.extend(namelist)

 print(Counter(nameoverall).most_common(3))
```

Comment: if names is a list of lists,use extend instead of append

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
name_freq = []
names= ['a','b','a','d','e','e','e','a']

for name in names:

    name_freq.append(name)

print(collections.Counter(name_freq).most_common(3))
```

**RESULT**

[('a', 3), ('e', 3), ('b', 1)]